# git label groups or stackoverflow type tagging

Tags: git, tags, label

Is there a way to use some sort of label for a type of git commit? It doesn't look like a **git-tag** is what I want, but something more like stackoverflow type tagging.

```
commit 1   <--  FIX            "Fixed bug 1"
commit 2   <--  SPECIAL_NEED   "1 hour on out of scope work"
commit 3   <--  FIX            "Fixed bug 2"
commit 4   <--  FIX            "Fixed bug 3"
commit 5   <--  SPECIAL_NEED   "2 hours on out of scope work"
```

Then later I need to see the list of commits and their messages that are labeled as SPECIAL_NEED.

```
commit 2   <--  SPECIAL_NEED   "1 hour on out of scope work"
commit 5   <--  SPECIAL_NEED   "2 hours on out of scope work"
```

Thanks

Comment: It sounds like you want a layer on top of Git.  I'm not aware of any Git feature that could implement something like this directly.

Comment: Some projects use a one word in the first line of the commit comment, like "bugfix", "feature", etc. `git tag`s only point to one commit (they are unique), it's not what you want. IMO, the best place to put that kind of information is the commit message.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just add the word `SPECIAL_NEED` to your commit message and search for it with

```
git log --grep=SPECIAL_NEED
```